# Add Task to Multiprocessing Pool of Parent

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

How can I add a new task to a `multiprocessing` pool that I initialized in a parent process? This following does not work:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool


def child_task(x):
    # the child task spawns new tasks
    results = p.map(grandchild_task, [x])
    return results[0]


def grandchild_task(x):
    return x


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(2)
    print(p.map(child_task, [0]))
    # Result: NameError: name 'p' is not defined
```

**Motivation**: I need to parallelize a program which consists of various child tasks, which themselves also have child tasks (i.e., grandchild tasks). Only parallelizing the child tasks OR the grandchild tasks does not utilize all my CPU cores.

In my use-case, I have various child tasks (maybe 1-50) and many grandchild tasks per child task (maybe 100-1000).

**Alternatives**: If this is not possible using Python's multiprocessing package, I am happy to switch to another library that supports this.

Comment: Couldn't you have more than one `Pool` — i.e. once at each "level"?

Comment: If I try that, I get the exception `daemonic processes are not allowed to have children`. Also, it would be quite slow (as it spawns a ton of processes overall), and it would be hard to determine how many processes to create at each level.

Comment: Hmm…OK, `map()` isn't the only way to submit tasks to a `Pool`, for example there's `apply_async()` — so it seems like the child tasks could submit their grandchild tasks that way to the existing one.

Comment: @martineau I tried that too just know and got the same exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked around more, and found [Ray](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/), which addresses this exact use case using [nested remote functions](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/advanced.html?highlight=nested#nested-remote-functions).

Answer (score 3):

There is such a thing as a minimal reproducible example and then there is going beyond that to remove so much code as to end up with something that (1) is perhaps too oversimplified with the danger than an answer could miss the mark and (2) couldn't possibly run as shown (you need to enclose the code that creates the Pool and submits the task in a block that is controlled by an `if __name__ == '__main__':` statement.

But based on what you have shown, I don't believe a Pool is the solution for you; you should be creating Process instances as they are required. One way to get the results from the Processes is to store them in a shareable, managed dictionary whose key is, for example, the process id of the Process that has created the result.

To expand on your example, the child task is passed two arguments, `x` and `y` and needs to return as a result `x**2 + 'y**2`. The child task will spawn two instances of grandchild task, each one computing the square of its argument. The child task will then combine the return values from these processes using addition:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
import os


def child_task(results_dict, x, y):
    # the child task spawns new tasks
    p1 = Process(target=grandchild_task, args=(results_dict, x))
    p1.start()
    pid1 = p1.pid
    p2 = Process(target=grandchild_task, args=(results_dict, y))
    p2.start()
    pid2 = p2.pid
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    pid = os.getpid()
    results_dict[pid] = results_dict[pid1] + results_dict[pid2]



def grandchild_task(results_dict, n):
    pid = os.getpid()
    results_dict[pid] = n * n


def main():
    manager = Manager()
    results_dict = manager.dict()
    p = Process(target=child_task, args=(results_dict, 2, 3))
    p.start()
    pid = p.pid
    p.join()
    # results will be stored with key p.pid:
    print(results_dict[pid])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```
13
```

**Update**

If you really had a situation where, for example, `child_task` needed to process N identical calls varying only in its arguments but it had to spawn a sub-process or two, then use a Pool as before but additionally pass a managed dictionary to `child_task` to be used for spawning additional Processes (*not* attempting to use a Pool for this) and retrieving their results.

**Update 2**

The only way I could figure out for the sub-processes themselves to use pooling is to use the `ProcessPoolExecutor` class from `concurrent.futures` module. When I attempted to do the same thing with `multiprocessing.Pool`, I got an error because we had daemon processes trying to create their own processes. But even here the only way is for each process in the pool to have its own pool of processes. You only have a finite number of processors/cores on your computer, so unless there is a bit of I/O mixed in the processing, you can create all these pools but the processes will be waiting for a chance to run. So, it's not clear what performance gains will be realized. There is also the problem of shutting down all the pools created for the `child_task` sub-processes. Normally a `ProcessPoolExecutor` instance is created using a `with` block and when that block is terminated the pool that was created is cleaned up. But `child_task` is invoked repeatedly and clearly cannot use `with` block because we don't want constantly to be creating and destroying pools. What I have come here is a bit of a kludge: A third parameter is passed, either True or False, indicating whether `child_task` should instigate a shutdown of its pool. The default value for this parameter is False, we don't even bother passing it. After all the actual results have been retrieved and the `child_task` processes are now idle, we submit N new tasks with dummy values but with `shutdown` set to True. Note that the `ProcessPoolExecutor` function `map` works quite a bit differently than the same function in the `Pool` class (read the docs):

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import time


child_executor = None


def child_task(x, y, shutdown=False):
    global child_executor

    if child_executor is None:
        child_executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)
    if shutdown:
        if child_executor:
            child_executor.shutdown(False)
            child_executor = None
            time.sleep(.2) # make sure another process in the pool gets the next task
        return None
    # the child task spawns new task(s)
    future = child_executor.submit(grandchild_task, y)
    # we can compute one of the results using the current process:
    return grandchild_task(x) + future.result()


def grandchild_task(n):
    return n * n


def main():
    N_WORKERS = 2
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=N_WORKERS) as executor:
        # first call is (1, 2), second call is (3, 4):
        results = [result for result in executor.map(child_task, (1, 3), (2, 4))]
        print(results)
        # force a shutdown
        # need N_WORKERS invocations:
        [result for result in executor.map(child_task, (0,) * N_WORKERS, (0,) * N_WORKERS, (True,) * N_WORKERS)]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```
[5, 25]
```

Comment: Thanks for the proposal, I did not know about `Manager`, that could help! In my use-case, I have various child tasks (maybe 1-50) and many grandchild tasks per child task (maybe 100-1000). Therefore, spawning a process per grandchild task is probably too expensive. It would be much better to have `Pool`-like functionality also for the grandchild tasks. Maybe there is a library for this?

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# requires Python version 3.8 or higher

from multiprocessing import Queue, Process
import time
from random import randrange
import os
import psutil


# function to be run by each child process
def square(number):
    sleep = randrange(5)
    time.sleep(sleep)
    print(f'Result is {number * number}, computed by pid {os.getpid()}...sleeping {sleep} secs')


# create a queue where all tasks will be placed
queue = Queue()

# indicate how many number of children you want the system to create to run the tasks
number_of_child_proceses = 5

# put all tasks in the queue above
for task in range(19):
    queue.put(task)


# this the main entry/start of the program when you run
def main():
    number_of_task = queue.qsize()
    print(f'{"_" * 60}\nBatch: {number_of_task // number_of_child_proceses + 1} \n{"_" * 60}')

    # don't create more number of children than the number of tasks. Also, in the last round, wait for all child process
    # to complete so as to wrap up everything
    if number_of_task <= number_of_child_proceses:
        processes = [Process(target=square, args=(queue.get(),)) for _ in
                     range(number_of_task)]
        for p in processes:
            p.start()
            p.join()

    else:
        processes = [Process(target=square, args=(queue.get(),)) for _ in range(number_of_child_proceses)]
        for p in processes:
            p.start()

    # update count of remaining task
    number_of_task = queue.qsize()

    # run the program in a loop until no more task remains in the queue
    while number_of_task:
        current_process = psutil.Process()
        children = current_process.children()

        # if children process have completed assigned task but there is still more remaining tasks in the queue,
        # assign them more tasks
        if not len(children) and number_of_task:
            print(f'\nAssigned tasks completed... reasigning the remaining {number_of_task} task(s) in the queue\n')
            main()

    # exit the loop if no more task in the queue to work on

    print('\nAll tasks completed!!')
    exit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the proposal! Unfortunately, I don't see how this solution allows me to (i) start grandchild processes, or to (ii) retrieve the result of my tasks.

Comment: Also, when I run this code on my machine, it does not seem to terminate.

Comment: Also, FWIW, code-only answer without any explanation like this are discouraged here on stackoverflow.